# Access GSdll32.dll in C++ or C++/CLI

Tags: c++, ghostscript

I have written a program that creates chess diagrams using post script.  I want to convert the resulting *.eps file to an equivalent *.jpg file using ghost script.  I have succeeded in doing this in a C# project but I cannot get it to work in C++ or C++/CLI, either one.  The problem is in getting access to the gsdll32.dll methods.

In C# I use this code:

```
[DllImport ("gsdll32.dll", EntryPoint = "gsapi_new_instance")]
private static extern int CreateAPIInstance (out IntPtr instance, IntPtr caller);
```

My attempts to use DllImport in C++ have failed.

In a C++/CLI project I get the following error when trying to add a reference:

> Could not add a reference to 'S:\ScruffySoft\UseGhostScript\bin\Debug\gsdll32.dll' as it is not of a type or version current project can use.

In a C++ project I added the gsdll32.dll as a 'Solution item' and when building get the error message:

> Error LNK1107 invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2B8   UseGhostScriptConsole S:\ScruffySoft\UseGhostScriptConsole\gsdll32.dll

So the question is: how do I get access to the ghost script DLL?

Thanks,
Dick

Comment: please share your attempts.

Comment: Are you building a 32-bit C++ application ? If not you won't be able to link to a 32-bit DLL.